# fastest way to set multiple values in specific indices in matlab for neural network output categorization reformation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, octave

There's a vector **y** which looks as below:

```
[
  1
  2
  4
]
```

I intend to transform it the following format, with only 0 and 1's, in which, current row's y-th element will be set as 1:

```
[
  1 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1
]
```

I could implement it in the following non-vectorized version, yet what's the most efficient way to fulfill that as well in vectorized version? Thanks!

```
yy = zeros(size(y, 1), num_labels);
for i=1:size(y,1),
    yy(i, y(i, 1)) = 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sparse matrix which will also save a lot of memory and can be used like a "normal" matrix in calculations:

```
y = [1 2 4];
sparse (y, y, 1)
```

gives you

```
Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 4, cols = 4, nnz = 3 [19%])

  (1, 1) ->  1
  (2, 2) ->  1
  (4, 4) ->  1
```

or If you really want a full matrix:

```
full (sparse (y, y, 1))
ans =

   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yet what I want is (1,1) -> 1, (2,2) -> 2, (3, 4) -> 4, so you can see that the first index is from 1,2,3,...,n, not exactly the same as the value of y.